# Php double quotes in array

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to use a few consecutive string replace functions.

Here is what I use:

```
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$newData = str_replace('\\', '', $data_string);
$NnewData = str_replace('"[', '[', $newData);
$FinalData = str_replace(']"', ']', $NnewData);
```

I'm looking for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you're doing what you're doing but you can make that a one-liner:

```
$final = str_replace(array('\\','"[', ']"'), array('', '[',']'), $data_string);
```

Basically `str_replace()` can take arrays for the search and replace parameters.

From [the manual](http://php.net/str_replace):

> If search and replace are arrays, then str_replace() takes a value from each array and uses them to search and replace on subject. If replace has fewer values than search, then an empty string is used for the rest of replacement values. If search is an array and replace is a string, then this replacement string is used for every value of search.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should take a look at the PHP doc ?

`str_replace` takes array in parameter ...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php